# MySql command line cyrillic Iinsert result is corrupted

Tags: mysql, character-set, command-line

Have putty connection.
Putty config : 
window-->translation-->remote character set-->utf-8
Launch command line `MySQL` client.
Perform insert  with cyrillic like:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `catName` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`catName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into category(catName) values ('абвгдйка');
```

The result is that corrupted cyrillic symbols inserted into DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default MySQL server is using latin1 character set for each incoming connection. Latin1, as you might know, does *not* support cyrillic symbols.

The simplest solution is to switch so called 'connection character set' by running `SET NAMES 'utf8';` in the beginning of each connection.

For example, this query should work:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';

CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `catName` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`catName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into category(catName) values ('привет русско-говорящему серверу');
```

To learn about character sets in MySQL and how to make the above change permament see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset.html).